# start teams-in-meeting-app on MeetingStage after join the meeting

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

is it possible to start in-meeting-app on MeetingStage after joining the meeting
(using TeamsJs or TeamsJsBlazorInterop), if someone from other attendees has already shared the app content?

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: Can you please share the repro steps or any doc link that you are following ?
Also, please refer this sample once: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-stage-view/nodejs

Comment: Yes if any attendee who has presenter role(not a moderated meeting), can initiate share to stage. If there is already something being shared on stage, it will stop and take over the stage.